# Sending ctrl-z to serial port in C (GSM SMS)

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, sms

I have written a code to send data to serial port /dev/ttyACM0. Basically this is used with the GSM modem to send an SMS. The AT command to set the sms in memory and send it are

First I need to write the following in serial port
"AT+CMGW=16\r"

Then write the following pdu converted message
069110090000F111000A9210299232900000AA03C8F40F
and then send ctrl-z

I have issues with sending ctrl-z

say message = "069110090000F111000A9210299232900000AA03C8F40F"
I have tried

```
strcat(message,"\x1A"); //Does not work
strcat(message,"\032"); //Does not work
```

I have even tried my hand at a function which adds a char to char*

```
void append(char *s,char c)
{
   int len = strlen(s);
   s[len] = c;
   s[len+1] = '\0';
}

append(message, '\032'); //Does not work
append(message, '\x1A'); //Does not work
```

I need to read the receive buffer of the port to check for the count
Example +CMGW:4

And then write 
AT+CMSS=3\r 
to send the message.

Typing the above AT commands on minicom sends the SMS. But in C code I just cannot type ctrl-z.

Does anyone know how to go about it?

Any help is appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Does it not append to the message or does it not send the ctrl-z?  If it does not send the ctrl-z, have you checked whether you are short by one character in the sending code?

Comment: @cup It seems that it appends. I see a weird looking symbol next to message on my receive buffer data. But once ctrl-z is sent I need to also receive +CMGW:<count> OK. I do not receive this at all. I just see the above commands and a weird symbol next to message, nothing following it. So I assume ctrl-z is not sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It was my mistake. I generalized the size of the data sent to the serial port. I think since the sent size defined was larger, the values following the ctrl-z hex value 0x1A  were garbage values. So my command could not save the sms in memory as it did not know the values following 0x1A meant. To solve this I used strlen to send the real size of the char * sent to the serial port.